# Activity recreates viewModel after splitscreen

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, dagger-2

I have an Activity, in which I'm providing view throw ViewModelFactory

ViewModelFactory

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator: Provider<out ViewModel>? = creators.get(modelClass)
        if (creator == null) {
            for (entry in creators.entries) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.key)) {
                    creator = entry.value
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        }
        try {
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("ERRORR", e.toString())
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }
}
```

Activity

```
    class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity(), Injectable, HasSupportFragmentInjector {
        @Inject
        lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

        @Inject
        lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
            val binding: MyLayoutBinding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.my_layout)
        }
}
```

All works just fine, but when I'm trying to go to splitscreen, my activity passes me in on create new instance of my ViewModel. But when I'm closing splitscreen and going to normal mode, my activity returns previous exam of my ViewModel. Where can be a problem?

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun activity(activity: MainActivity): Activity

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: MyViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainViewModel::class)
    abstract fun MyViewModel(mainViewModel: MyViewModel): ViewModel



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you should not set your `ViewModel` in `onCreate()`.

You could set it right away or using a lazy.

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by lazy {
  ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}
```

That, directly as one of your Activity's members.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work. I still have another instance of viewModel when making split screen, but I will have the same instance of vm when turn splitscreen off